# What is the correct syntax for using a command block to place a wall sign

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to use the /setblock command to place a wall sign and while I manage to find success in placing the sign, it doesn't include the text. I have looked all over and there seems to be various ways to write the command. This is the command that I got to work:

> /setblock    minecraft:wall_sign 4 replace
>   {Text1:{text:""},Text2:{text:"Room"},Text3:{text:"Two"},Text4:{text:""}}

Here is an image of the sign posted when the command is entered:
[image: wall_sign placed with no text]

I don't understand why it is placing the sign without the text. I have read the wiki and even seen other sources say that all I need in the code is the following:

> /setblock    minecraft:wall_sign 4 replace
>   {Text2:"Room",Text3:"Two"}

However, this always gives me an error, as you can see in this picture:
[image: error messages]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [text portion](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sign#Text) should be specified in [JSON format](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Raw_JSON_text).

Example command:

```
/setblock <x> <y> <z> wall_sign 4 replace {Text2:"{\"text\":\"Room\"}",Text3:"{\"text\":\"Two\"}"}
```

I recommend visiting the [wiki on signs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sign), specifically the [block entity section](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sign#Block_entity) for more information.

Comment: Thanks once again. I must say, there are a lot of bad examples out there.

Comment: They probably aren't bad as often as they are outdated.  Lots of versions of Minecraft, lots of command changes.